# Submission of two papers in one conference?

Tags: conference, computer-science, paper-submission

I wanted to know whether it is allowed and also plausible to submit two papers at the same conference? Does the acceptance or rejection of one affect the acceptance or rejection of the other paper?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing wrong or unusual in submitting two papers on a single conference. For specific detail you should refer to the conference author guide. In my experience, there exists an upper bound of papers (about 3-4), but I have never encountered a conference where only a single paper was permitted.

The acceptance or rejection is individual, every paper is peer-reviewed on its own account.

You should keep in mind that the conference will charge every paper separately. You should also watch the presentation schedule for any conflicts (though, they are very unlikely)

Comment: I've never encountered a conference where a single author could not be on multiple papers, but I have encountered a conference where a single individual was not allowed to be first author and/or present (not sure which) on more than one. Just more reason to check the rules for the conference :-)

Comment: "that the conference will charge every paper separately" - this does happen sometimes, but the word *will* is a bit strong here IMHO, given that it is not necessarily the case (especially if the papers are of different "classes", e.g. one full paper and one short paper or one poster).

Comment: @SimonW: I once encountered such a conference. My professor considered that completely inacceptable and started a fight with the conference organizers over it (which he won eventually, I was allowed to present two papers) :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper honestly, the only instances where conference charges nothing that come to mind are (undergrad) student papers and invited papers. However, my statement was primarily meant to emphasize that one should not expect to present multiple papers for the fee of one.

Comment: @user3209815: It is true that conferences often have a (quite low) upper limit of papers included in the registration, but more than one is not uncommon: ["one full or limited registration is valid for up to 3 papers"](http://im2015.ieee-im.org/authors), ["one full registration is valid for up to 3 papers"](http://infocom2015.ieee-infocom.org/attendees/registration), ["one full registration is valid for up to 3 papers"](http://wcnc2015.ieee-wcnc.org/registration), etc. Alternatively, the second paper sometimes costs less than a full extra registration if first authors match.

Comment: Weird. The conferences I attend only charge to _attend_, not to _present_, and the same speaker giving multiple talks (at no additional charge, of course) is quite common.

Answer (score 12):

> I wanted to know whether it is allowed and also plausible to submit two papers at the same conference?

Yes, it's generally allowed. (Unless the submission instructions explicitly forbid this.)

It's also plausible - it's even common. If your work is closely related to the scope of a particular conference, it's not uncommon for you to have multiple pieces of work to submit. (This is especially true if there are not many conferences in your subfield; you might choose to "save up" publications for a particular venue, rather than submit them somewhere else where they will be on the edge of the conference scope.)

> Does the acceptance or rejection of one affect the acceptance or rejection of the other paper?

No, papers are generally reviewed independently and each submission of evaluated on its own merit.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely check the conference website. For instance, one in my field (not CS admittedly) rejects automatically anything with the same first author.

https://www.eshg.org/abstracts2015.0.html

Comment: This is major difference between fields: I have *never* heard of such a policy for a CS conference.  In CS, this would be tantamount to saying you can only publish one article in a journal per year.

Comment: @jakebeal The question is about conferences, not journals.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Maybe my comment is unclear. I meant to make an analogy: restricting a CS researcher to one submission to their primary conference would be like restricting a researcher in another field to one submission per year to their primary journal.  In other words, not at all reasonable.

Comment: @jakebeal OK, I see what you mean. But I don't think the analogy is really helpful: it's essentially saying "Doing that would be just like doing something that's almost identical to the first thing!" which isn't a very strong statement.

Answer (score 1):

My two little cents: 
It is of course generally allowed. I personally, did that a couple of times (2 or 3 papers). I have different experiences. There were conferences where both of the papers were accepted.

However, at one conference both of my papers were sent to one reviewer (though there were other reviewers). And that particular reviewer though that the underlying formulation of both of papers were same (!), which sounded as a serious accusation and the editor of the conference rejected one of the papers. I responded to the reviewers that the problems presented in two papers were completely different, though both of them definitely had some similar (15-20%) formulations. *I am a PhD student working in a single funded research project; so there will always be some similarities in formulation among my publications.*

There is another point to consider (which is my personal speculation) - when the conference editor/publication chair sees a number of paper from the same author, he/she might think, just might, you are using the conference as a dumping ground or just trying to save money (as usually papers after the first one gets some discounts) and reject the paper when the reviewers' give neutral comments. I may be completely wrong though.